# How to save and close excel worksheet

Tags: c#

how to close excel work sheet,i want save only excel worksheet not open,this code save and open excel worksheet how to avoid that

```
for (int h = 0; h < Dtb.Rows.Count; h++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Dtb.Columns.Count; j++)//dataGridView1.Columns.Count
    {
        wksht.Cells[h + 1, j + 1] = Dtb.Rows[h].ItemArray[j];        
    }
}

wksht.SaveAs("C:\\Barcodes\\New\\" + BatchCode + " " + Date + "_" + k + ".xlsx");
```

Comment: so you've got it saving do wksht.Close(); if you dont want to see it opened, make sure you hide excel..

Comment: i tryed but it dosent worked  ' wksht.SaveAs("C:\\Barcodes\\New\\" + BatchCode + " " + Date + "_" + k + ".xlsx");
                    wksht.Visible = false;'

Comment: In what way did it not work? I didnt say make the worksheet not visible, I said hide EXCEL.. the app. somewhere you should have something like excel = new Excel.Application(), then do excel.visible=false; it wont show on screen..  so.. what exactly "didnt work" if it didnt save the file - I would look at the "date" variable..

Answer (score 0):

> I tried below code and is working fine for me.

```
workbook.SaveAs(exportpathtxt.Text, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```